# How to install Python ttk themes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

This is my first post on SO, so please feel free to correct me if I'm doing anything wrong!

I am making a simple GUI for my Raspberry Pi (that runs Raspbian stretch) on Windows (because I can use PyCharm on there).
I am would like to install third party themes from [this site](https://github.com/RedFantom/ttkthemes)  and have followed the instructions on the wiki. However, on both Windows and Raspbian, it appears to install properly without any errors, but when I check for ttk by doing this:

```
import tkinter.ttk
tkinter.ttk.Style().theme_names()
```

it still displays the default themes for the respective operating systems.

I have also looked at this SO post ([How to find or install themes tkinter ttk for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610323/how-to-find-or-install-themes-tkinter-ttk-for-python)), but there are no relevant answers on there.

**Edit:** I now know how to use the themes in a regular tkinter/ttk GUI, but I would like to install these themes so they act like the built in ones, as I am using the [appJar](http://appjar.info) module that uses tkinter and ttk.

Any help and guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

appJar's support for ttk is still in development, but you can try overriding the default style:

```
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
app = gui(useTtk=True)
app.ttkStyle = ThemedStyle(app.topLevel)
app.ttkStyle.set_theme("plastik")
```

This tells appJar to use ttk, but then replaces the style appJar is using, with the style you request.

Comment: It is a nice surprise seeing the developer of appJar respond to my question! To get this to work, had to change `ThemedStyle(app.topLevel)`to include brackets so it looks like this: `ThemedStyle(app.topLevel())`. I also (accidentally) made a typo, so that the 'L' of topLevel was in lowercase. This made it work, (with appJar complaining about an unknown function) but when I made the 'L' uppercase, I got `TypeError: 'Tk' object is not callable` and the program will not run. Is this because ttk support is still in beta? Or is it because of other issues?

Comment: app.topLevel is the Tk object. So if you put brackets after it, you'll get the `not callable` error. Try removing the brackets, and making sure the typo is still fixed.

Comment: It worked! I apologise for not following instructions carefully - I guess I was just tired last night. May I suggest that you put these instructions on the appJar website, so that others can see? Because imho, the default ttk themes are quite poor and I think that other appJar users will appreciate this.

Comment: Good to hear it works. I've already added in support for tkthemes and updated the docs for the next release :)

Comment: Great news, and sorry for bothering you again, but I have found that when using ttk and images, the program doesn't run and gives me `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"`. When run without ttk, everything works fine. Any suggestions? (Also, please let me know if this should be opened in a separate question)

Comment: Actually, it would be much better to raise issues on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jarvisteach/appJar).

Images don't support ttk in the current release, but they will in the next one (and are available in the next_release branch).

Comment: As you are already aware of this issue, I'll leave it for now, but with any future issues, I'll raise them on GitHub :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you imported their package? And according to their *current* docs, you check for themes basically by:

```
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk   
import ttk   #(might need to add tkinter. beforehand)
window = tk.ThemedTk()
window.get_themes()
```

Have you tried that method?

Comment: Thank you for helping. This does work, (yay!) so it's good to know that it's properly installed. However, (and sorry about not mentioning it in the original question) I am using a module called [appJar](http://appjar.info) that uses tkinter and ttk. Do you know of any way to install the themes so that they act like built in themes?
Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: AFAIK no, the documentation really is scarce, you can try copying the theme files to the directory of installed themes (which would involve some tinkering) but may I ask why do you want to do that exactly? Btw, PyCharm is cross platform. And since you've stated that you'd like some guidance, avoid comments that include 'thank you for...' (instead vote up or accept or both) and welcome to SO :)

Comment: To clarify what I would like to do, the appJar module only picks up the built in themes, and it would be fairly difficult to modify it to import the ttkthemes module. So if the ttkthemes themes were installed in the same manner as the built in ones, then appJar should (in theory) pick them up and use them. Hopefully I've explained this clearly...

With PyCharm, I don't think that there is an ARM version for Raspberry Pi, but if there is, please let me know.

Comment: Pardon considering the PyCharm, even if there was you shouldn't try to run it as it's relatively heavy, I didn't understand that you wanted to run it on RPi. As per themes, AppJar seems to still be in beta considering ttk support  and they still suffer from a ton of bugs, so I guess time will tell, perhaps they'll add support for non-default themes, we'll see.